# Adding metadata to MIME multipart message

Tags: python, email

I'm sending emails using python. Currently my technique is this:

```
msg = email.mime.Multipart.MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = username
msg["To"] = recipient
msg["Subject"] = subject
mimeText = email.mime.Text.MIMEText(body, "html")
msg.attach(mimeText)

stringMsg = msg.as_string()
```

I would like to also add some metadata to the message - specifically, a unique identifier of the task the email is achieving, so that when it is checked later (possibly by a different service), I can avoid sending a duplicate email.

This metadata doesn't need to be completely secret or secure, just something that standard email clients don't render. Obviously there are the options of including a bogus BCC email address containing the id, or adding a hidden html node to the body.

```
<div style="display:none;">123456789</div>
```

But both of those seem quite "hacky". Is there anything like this that will get persisted and sent as part of the email, that I can check using `imaplib` later?

```
msg["secretMetadata"] = "123456789"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User defined fields are permitted and explained in [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-4.7.5). Basically you can prefix your custom field with `X-` and this will not conflict with any existing fields nor extension fields.

So, something like `msg["X-secretMetadata"] = "123456789"` should suffice.

Comment: That sounds promising - but according to this that convention has been deprecated: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648 . Is there any risk involved in using them?

Comment: @user1002973 - good pickup, I hadn't looked that deeply. According to RFC6648 appendix B, if your meta data is sufficiently unique, and there is no chance that it could be standardised, then you can use your own header. Instead of using "X-" you could use your company's name or domain name somewhere in the header field's name. Or you could go for something like a UUID for the header name. Only you can judge whether that is warranted or not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use X-headers.  Information in the X-headers of an email message is usually used for application-specific purposes, and this information is usually not displayed by mail clients.